# Wireless hotspot not supported after upgrade to 14.04!

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, hot-spot

I used to use ap-hotspot on my laptop with Saucy without a problem. Now that I upgraded to 14.04 and installed ap-hotspot I get this error:

```
Your wireless card or driver does not support Access Point mode
```

Here is the output of `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

and here the output of `iw list`:

```
Wiphy phy0
Band 1:
    Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 1.0 Mbps
        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
Band 2:
    Frequencies:
        * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
        * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5190 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5210 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5230 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5260 MHz [52] (disabled)
        * 5280 MHz [56] (disabled)
        * 5300 MHz [60] (disabled)
        * 5320 MHz [64] (disabled)
        * 5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
        * 5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
        * 5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
        * 5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
        * 5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
        * 5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
        * 5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
        * 5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
        * 5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
        * 5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
        * 5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
        * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
        * 5920 MHz [184] (disabled)
        * 5940 MHz [188] (disabled)
        * 5960 MHz [192] (disabled)
        * 5980 MHz [196] (disabled)
        * 6000 MHz [200] (disabled)
        * 6020 MHz [204] (disabled)
        * 6040 MHz [208] (disabled)
        * 6060 MHz [212] (disabled)
        * 6080 MHz [216] (disabled)
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
max # scan SSIDs: 1
max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
Supported Ciphers:
    * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
    * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
    * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
    * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
    * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
software interface modes (can always be added):
interface combinations are not supported
Supported commands:
     * set_interface
     * new_key
     * join_ibss
     * set_pmksa
     * del_pmksa
     * flush_pmksa
     * connect
     * disconnect
```

Output of `rfkill list wifi`:

```
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Out put of `lspci -vnn | grep -A2 Network`:

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
```

I swear it used to work in Saucy. Can it be a problem with the driver?

Comment: Post the output of `rfkill list wifi` and `lspci -vnn | grep -A2 Network` in your body of question.

Comment: Hi I just posted the output.

Comment: Have you referred to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453877/starting-wireless-hotspot-but-nothing-happens) post ?

Comment: @Reza And have a look to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot) post.

Comment: @Reza what I've noticed in both mine and @KasiyA links  is that it requires `hostapd` package. Have you installed that ?

Comment: Yes, hostapd is installed. In the post that Kasiya mentioned there is a link to Ubuntu documentation where it says: "Broadcom cards support master mode using the reverse-engineered kernel driver. You need to enable (or make as a module) the Softmac wireless extensions and BCM43xx wireless driver." I think this must be the clue although I don't know how to do so.

Comment: @chili555: Care to have a look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this: [Wireless adapters/Chipset table](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table) master mode is not supported in the proprietary bcmwl driver and is supported in the native b43 with required firmware. I recommend you do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update && sudo update-pciids
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot
```

Test:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master
```

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said. ap-hotspot works now and I could make a hotspot but neither my Linux laptop nor my android device can connect to it. (They can't get the ip address). The test you mentioned returns: Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.

Comment: @Reza Before setting mode , the interface has to be brought down. Do `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` then `sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master` then `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up'. If chili's answer helped, remember to upvote and accept

Comment: I assume then, that hostap was able to switch to master mode. I am not experienced in hostap and have no suggestions to troubleshoot why no IP address is given.

Comment: IP address problem was caused by ufw. I wish I knew hot to allow ap-hotspot in ufw....

Comment: Have you tried experimentally disabling ufw? sudo ufw disable

Comment: Yes I've done so but would like to enable it back again with hotspot allowed.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://askubuntu.com/questions/353338/ufw-allow-from-wlan-to-eth